# GCS NodeJS APIs requests returning empty

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am following the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) for authenticating to my GCS project. I have downloaded by service account credentials and I have exported the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. Just to be safe though, I'm explicitly pointing the API to my file. Here is what I have:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: '{my_project_id}',
    keyFilename: '{my_file_path}',
});

storage
    .getBuckets()
    .then(results => {
        const buckets = results[0];

        console.log('Buckets:');
        buckets.forEach(bucket => {
            console.log(bucket.name);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
```

When I run this with node, the only output I get is:

```
Buckets:
```

Implying that my storage was successfully queried and no buckets were found.

However there's a few problems. I know that my buckets exist because I can use `gsutil ls` to see all my buckets correctly. Also, if I change the `projectId` or `keyFilename` fields to be totally invalid, I get the same behavior.

If I wasn't authenticated, I would have expected some kind of error, but it's clear that even with a completely invalid key file, it still doesn't produce errors.

What steps can I take to debug this? Without an error code I don't have much to go on.

Comment: Try `gcloud auth application-default revoke` and try again, there should be some error appears

Comment: @CloudAce I ran that command and it gave me an error because my default credentials have not been set up. I set them up and logged in, but I got the same result. I noticed that the `gcloud auth` command also supports logging in with a service account which is what i want to do, so I logged in there as well but still no change.

Comment: Let's remove all credentials and try. `mv ~/.config/gcloud ~/.config/gcloud.bak` , `unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS ` ,   `//keyFilename: '{my_file_path}',`  and try. there must be unauth error. Then either export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or use keyFilename.

Comment: @CloudAce I tried that, and unfortunately the exact same thing happened. I created a new project in python and tried following the tutorial, and I think I found my error. Python generated a "file not found" error. Turns out you cannot use `~` for your home directory otherwise it won't find it. So I gave the node version the absolute path and it worked. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem. But if you comment out keyFilename, and use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS only, it should work even if you use `~`. And if you set  `keyFilename: '~/path/to/file'`, nodejs will throw ENOENT error as nodejs will try to locate `$PWD/~/path/to/file`

Comment: Yeah, it seems like it should have, but it definitely wasn't throwing anything. Or if it was, it was getting suppressed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem is that I specified the file path as `~/path/to/file` because `~` doesn't mean anything outside of a shell like bash.

I have no idea why Node was silently failing here rather than telling me that it couldn't find the file, but that was definitely the problem, it worked after supplying the full path.